# Dojo Custom Build with Gridx

Tags: dojo, dependencies, custom-build, dojo.gridx

So I have been trying to get my DOJO to build after adding in the gridx widgets

I have added the gridx modules in my app.profile.js file like this:

```
layers: {
    "gridx/gridx": {
        include: [
            "gridx/Grid",
            "gridx/core/model/cache/Async",
            "gridx/modules/CellWidget",
            "gridx/modules/Edit",
            "gridx/modules/Filter",
            "gridx/modules/Pagination",
            "gridx/modules/pagination/PaginationBar"
                ]
    }
}
```

During the compile I keep getting these errors.

error(311) Missing dependency. module: app/screen; dependency: js/plugins/gridx/Grid
error(311) Missing dependency. module: app/screen; dependency: js/plugins/gridx/core/model/cache/Async
error(311) Missing dependency. module: app/screen; dependency: js/plugins/gridx/modules/CellWidget
error(311) Missing dependency. module: app/screen; dependency: js/plugins/gridx/modules/Edit
error(311) Missing dependency. module: app/screen; dependency: js/plugins/gridx/modules/Filter
error(311) Missing dependency. module: app/screen; dependency: js/plugins/gridx/modules/Pagination
error(311) Missing dependency. module: app/screen; dependency: js/plugins/gridx/modules/pagination/PaginationBar

Not sure what I am missing here I have been troubleshooting for a while now.

packages.json Code

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "dojo": "current",
        "dijit": "current",
        "dojox": "current",
        "util": "current",
        "gridx": "current",
    },
    "description": "app Components Package",
    "dojoBuild": "app-common.profile.js"
}
```

Comment: It looks like the build doesn't know where the gridx source code is located.  Can you post the packages part of your build profile?

Comment: Added the packages.json code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build profile needs a packages section which will tell the build where the gridx code is located.

**build.profile.js**

```
basePath:       "../dojo-release-1.8.3-src",
...
packages:[
    {name: 'dojo', location: 'dojo'},
    {name: 'dijit', location: 'dijit'},
    {name: 'dojox', location: 'dojox'},
    {name: 'gridx', location: '../PATH/TO/gridx'} // path is relative from basePath
],
```

Comment: This was part of the solution.  In one of my classes I had an issue with relative path during the build process.  On my local dev server it would be fine but during the building process it would error out and not find the correct path.